# Take process input from either of two channels

Tags: nextflow

How do I allow a process to take an input from either one of two channels that are outputs of processes with mutually exclusive conditions for running? For example, something like:

```
params.condition = false

process a {
    output:
    path "a.out" into a_into_c

    when:
    params.condition == true

    """
    touch a.out
    """
}

process b {
    output:
    path "b.out" into b_into_c

    when:
    params.condition == false

    """
    touch b.out
    """
}

process c {
    publishDir baseDir, mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path foo from a_into_c or b_into_c

    output:
    path "final.out"

    """
    echo $foo > final.out
    """
}
```

where final.out will contain `a.out` if params.condition is true (e.g. `--condition` is given on the command line), and `b.out` if it is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [mix operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#mix) for this:

```
process c {
    publishDir baseDir, mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path foo from a_into_c.mix(b_into_c)

    output:
    path "final.out"

    """
    echo $foo > final.out
    """
}
```